# I need help creating a scoring system, but it keeps giving me an error, the commented out integers are the parts giving me trouble

Tags: c++, integer

I found an RPS game and wanted to improve on it by creating a scoring system but the //int compwin = compwin + 1; keeps giving me errors. I am still fairly new to coding in C++ and have no clue where the problem is standing so thanks for helping in advance. Also this code was taken from somewhere this is not my code but I wanted to try and improve on it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <limits>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int choice;
    int i;
    int y;
    int Y;
    int comp;
    char res;
    int compwin = 0;
    int choicewin = 0;
    unsigned seed;
    while (1==1) {
        //The choices
        cout << "Game Choices.\n\n";
        cout << "1.Rock\n";
        cout << "2.Paper\n";
        cout << "3.Scissors\n";
        cout << "4.Quit, exits the game.\n\n";
        cout << "Please enter your choice.\n\n";
        cin >> choice;
        //-----------------------Player Imputs-----------------------------------
        if (choice == 1) //Rock
        {
            cout << "You picked Rock.\n";
            cout << "Now here was my choice.\n\n";
        }
        else if (choice == 2) //Paper
        {
            cout << "You picked Paper.\n";
            cout << "Now here was my choice.\n\n";
        }
        else if (choice == 3) //Scissors
        {
            cout << "You picked Scissors.\n";
            cout << "Now here was my choice.\n\n";
        }
        else if (choice == 4)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (choice != 1 || 2 || 3 || 4) // Debug
        {
            cout << "Uhhhh thats not one of the following.\n\nGoodbye!\n\n";
            system("pause");
            return 0;
        }
        //-------------------------Computer Choice-------------------------------
        seed = time(0);
        srand(seed); //RNG TIME
        comp = rand() % 3 + 1; //Computer picks 
        if (comp == 1) //Computer rock
        {
            res = 1;
            cout << "Rock!\n\n";
        }
        else if (comp == 2) //Computer paper
        {
            res = 2;
            cout << "Paper!\n\n";
        }
        else if (comp == 3)  // Computer scissors
        {
            res = 3;
            cout << "Scissors!\n\n";
        }
        //-----------------------Victory Conditions------------------------------
        if (comp == 1 && choice == 1) {
            std::cout << "It was a tie!" << endl;
        }
        else if (comp == 1 && choice == 3) {
            std::cout << "I Won! Better luck next time!" << endl;
            //int compwin = compwin + 1; This is where the problem occurs
        }
        else if (comp == 2 && choice == 2) {
            std::cout << "It was a tie!" << endl;
        }
        else if (comp == 2 && choice == 1) {
            std::cout << "I Won! Better luck next time!" << endl;
            //int compwin = compwin + 1; This is where the problem occurs
        }
        else if (comp == 2 && choice == 3) {
            std::cout << "It was a tie!" << endl;
        }
        else if (comp == 2 && choice == 2) {
            std::cout << "I Won! Better luck next time!" << endl;
            //int compwin = compwin + 1; This is where the problem occurs
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Congrats! You won!" << endl;
            //int choicewin = choicewin + 1; This is where the problem occurs
        }
        cout << "Heres the score, computer =" << compwin << "and player =" << choicewin;
        cout << "Want to go again? (y/n)";
        cin >> res;
        system("cls");
    }
    while (res == y || Y);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (choice != 1 || 2 || 3 || 4)` is always true. `c++` does not work as you expect. You can't skip the `choice !=` part. `while (res == y || Y);` same bug here but in this case you have a second bug as well. are `y` and `Y` variables? Comparison to a character needs to be single quoted like this: `'y'`

Comment: `//int compwin = compwin + 1; ` makes no sense regardless. The `int` part of those two decls shouldn't be there. `compwin` is already declared above the loop; all you appear to desire is updating its value; not declare a pointless local var that hides the one outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the help and i have gone and changed the code and everything works as should

Comment: Take a look at [std::none_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of)

Answer (score 2):

This

```
int compwin = compwin + 1;
```

is a declaration and initialization. A rather weird one, and to discuss why it is allowed would take us on a too big detour. So lets look at a simpler example:

```
int compwin = 1;   // declares compwin and initializes it with 1
int compwin = 2;   // compiler error, because compwin is already declared
```

You can only declare the same variable once (again the long complete truth is more involved, search for "shadowing" in case you care). You also only need to initialize a variable only once.

If you want to assign something to an already declared variable, you use assignment, as in

```
int compwin = 1;   // declare and initialize
compwin = 2;       // assign
```

Further note that

```
else if (choice != 1 || 2 || 3 || 4) // Debug
```

is not doing what you expect. The correct way is

```
else if (choice != 1 && choice != 2 && choice != 3 && choice != 4)
```

The mistake is a combination of ignoring [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) and a wrong combination of several conditions. The `operator||` expects a `bool` on both sides and unfortunately numbers happily convert to `true` (only `0` becomes `false`), but a good compiler may spit out warnings on that. Similar mistake is on `while (res == y || Y);`.